# jQuery ajax - diacritical characters encoding

Tags: jquery, ajax, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm sending data wrapped in XML formatting to a server, using jquery's ajax() method:

```
url = "http://mysite.com/service/command";    
input = "my string";
xml = "<request><space>"+space_id+"</space><input>"+input+"</input></request>";
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: url,
    dataType: 'xml;charset=UTF-8',
    data: xml
});
```

If diacritical characters exist in the **input** string that is passed to the method's "data" property, those characters get converted to some other bizarre combinations before being sent off to the server, despite the UTF-8 character encoding. 
Bellow, as an example, is the data that is being submitted to the server, with the input string being **ääää**. I've copied it from Chrome's developer tools-->Network:

```
<request><space>2080878</space><input>Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤</input></request>
```

How can I solve this problem and prevent diacritics from being "twisted" like this?

Comment: Probably also depends on the page-encoding and the server-encoding (how is the server parsing the XmlHTTP request? There are several servers that default to other encodings..

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve it:

1. Save your JavaScript in UTF-8 encoded form. If you use "notepad" use "File->Save as" from Menu and choose "UTF-8" as encoding in the lower right left to the "SAVE"-Button.
   Reason: input = "äää"; must be saved into the file as UTF-8 encoded Characters.
2. If input is received from input elements (e.g. textarea, input lines) tell the browser it's UTF-8 encoded in several ways. One possibility is to add a HTTP-header like following (if this is the output of a script (e.g. PHP or ASP)):

   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
3. If not possible, put a META-Tag into the header of the html file which is using the script like this:

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
4. Add a DOCTYPE to the html-file that includes/executes the script. Reason: Some browsers do interpret html without DOCTYPE with some old compatibility mechanism which assumes a ISO-8859-1 Encoding or something like this. There are even worse effects in JavaScript that I noted... so always add a DOCTYPE like this one (doesn't need to be "strict") at the beginning of your HTML document:

   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Hope that helps ;-)